# MkMapView Zoom Frame find.

Tags: dictionary, zooming

Thanks in Advance.

How to detect the Zoom level of the map in iOS.
Means just like finding the Scroll View hight like that how to find particular zoom level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395

-(int) Mapzoomlevel {

    return 21- round(log2(self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta *
                          MERCATOR_RADIUS * M_PI / (180.0 * self.mapView.bounds.size.width)));

}

-(void)zoom_level_in_floatvalue {

    NSLog(@"%f",[self Mapzoomlevel]);

}
```